# MariaDB: Why is this still using temporary and filesort - is it because I'm using a self-join? How to fix?

Tags: index, mariadb, temporary-tables, self-join

```
SELECT  e2.personId, COUNT(*)
   
FROM        entries e1
JOIN        entries e2   ON  e2.categoryId   =   e1.categoryId
                        AND  e2.personId    !=   e1.personId
   
WHERE       e1.personId  =  1
   
GROUP BY    e2.personId
```

gives:

```
id   select_type   table   type   key                   key_length   ref                     rows   extra
1    SIMPLE        e1      ref    personId_categoryId   4            const                   59     Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE        e2      ref    categoryId_personId   4            project.e1.categoryId   8      Using where; Using index
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` I get "Using index".

What's the problem here?  Is it something to do with joining a table onto itself?

(The indexes present on the table are the two shown in the explain output, containing the columns that the names suggest.)

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `entries` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `personId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `personId_categoryId` (`personId`,`categoryId`),
  KEY `categoryId_personId` (`categoryId`,`personId`),
  CONSTRAINT `entries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`personId`) REFERENCES `people` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `entries_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1465605 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Show table's DDL.

Comment: Added to the question now @Akina

Comment: `categoryId_personId` index exists. So everything is OK. *Why is this still using temporary and filesort* - unequiation condition does not allow to use index for grouping. Moreover, "using index" in a query without grouping means that the index is used as covering (as compact version of the table), I think.

Comment: I've tried removing the != condition (I could just filter it out in PHP afterwards) but it made no difference to the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: (If that's what you meant by "unequiation")

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your query to

```
SELECT e2.personId, COUNT(*) - SUM(e2.personId = e1.personId)
FROM entries e1
JOIN entries e2 USING (categoryId)
WHERE e1.personId  =  1
GROUP BY e2.personId
```

---

### Update

It seems that MariaDB uses implicit STRAIGHT_JOIN... or plan builder cannot optimize the query correctly.

For query optimize it's enough to swap table copies. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=341a84035a35cdb4badcd6093429136d) for details.

Comment: Three times slower and still `Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`.  (Additionally to make them equal I had to add in `AND e2.personId != 1`, but the results were largely the same either way.

Comment: @Codemonkey The answer updated - check.

Comment: Interesting - not used dbfiddle before, looks like a useful tool.  Sadly even with the bottom option I still get temp/filesort when using it on this machine.  I will investigate more later, thank you.

Comment: @Codemonkey Execution plan depends on table data  and current statistic primarily - try to perform `ANALYZE TABLE` or even `OPTIMIZE TABLE` - maybe it will give some effect...

Comment: I'm out at the moment but will try those when I get home. The data has high cardinality so it should be good for an index, from what little I understand!

Comment: I still get the same thing; maybe due to the part of the DDL you commented out, who knows.